# Best way to change bootstrap navbar brand logo image after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The way I have it set up, once you scroll past the header section, the navbar goes from transparent to a solid color for the rest of the 1 page site. Links, styles etc change in a function that adds/removes a css class depending if it's past the header or not.

How would I go about swapping a new logo though? I'm not sure how to change an actual element like that instead of just appending a CSS class. It's a .png file and when the navbar changes color I'd like a different logo that is styled differently to be displayed. Also, is it possible to transition the changing of logos so it's not a dramatic jump? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide a link or JSFilddle.

Comment: I don't really need the code I'm just not sure what function or method I can use to actually change the logo image based on scroll.

Comment: I made a navbar just like that, with a logo changing after scrolling, from red to white, I made it with JQuery, pretty straightforward.

Comment: About the method: When reaching breakingpoint toggle CSS classes for both logos (1 visible, 1 invisible), position them absolute so they are stacked up!

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this would be to absolutely position the 2 images on top of eachother in a parent div. Then have a class that sets `opacity: 1` to the image on top, with a `transition`, and remove the class when scrolling so it has `opacity: 0`

Comment: Ahh sneaky! I like it.